# Error while trying to shutdown the kernel on Jupyter Notebook python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
    377     elif game == 100:
--> 379         os._exit()

TypeError: Required argument 'status' (pos 1) not found
```

Comment: pro tip: if a method/function name starts with a `_`, you probably should not use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass an argument in the "_exit" function.
You can try this:

```
os._exit(0)
```